# Firebase JavaScript getting the UID and using it to write info to a real-time database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have written a simple JavaScript login/ signup for and am now trying to add Firebase so it will log in and out.

I have got up to the point where I am able to create an account, login and display the account email on the account page.

My next step would be to take the firstName and lastName from the input boxes and assign it to the users UID in a real-time database using Firebase.

After, doing some experimenting, reading the docs and debugging errors, I have managed to print the UID into the console, but when attempting to print the first and last name, I get ‘undefined’.

Please help me to be able to display the firstName and lastName in the account page.

Here is the code:

—SignUp Page https://jsfiddle.net/dq8o1tLv/1/

—Login Page https://jsfiddle.net/Lj312egr/1/

```
Thank.you
```

Comment: When you register, you register using email and password. So only this information is sent to the database. How do you expect to receive information you haven't sent ?

Comment: Also, on line 90, you are logging ```proFirstName``` and ```proLastName``` before assigning them the value. That could be the problem why you are getting undefined.

Comment: @CanUver Sorry, I haven’t explained it very well, I am trying to send the firstName, lastName and UID, the next steps would be me trying receive it.

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi That solves the undefined error, but now instead of ‘undefined’ it is just a blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current user UID, you must call the function `onAuthStateChanged` and get the UID

There is an exemple :

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if(user){
    uid = user.uid;
  }
});
```

You can create a global variable called uid to stock the user UID

and then you can get the user infos from the database like :

```js
firebase.database().ref(uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
  document.getElementById('firstname').innerText = snapshot.val().firstname;
  document.getElementById('lastname').innerText = snapshot.val().lastname;
});
```

To set the users info in database, you can use :

```js
firebase.database().ref(uid).set({
  firstname: document.getElementById('firstname').value,
  lastname: document.getElementById('lastname').value
}).then(function(){
  console.log('User added!');
});
```

I hope that my answer will be clear to you and that it will have helped you